# How do I convert List of String array to nested list of type String?

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot

How do I convert `List<String[]>` to `List<List<String>>`?

```
List<String[]> allData = csv.readAll();
```

allData needs to be coverted in `List<List<String>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stream and `Arrays::asList` which will convert `String[]` to a `List<String>`, like this:

```
List<List<String>> response = allData.stream()
        .map(Arrays::asList)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or just .toList();
```